# Displaying filesize on the user interface

Tags: user-interface

I have been using following function to display the file size in bytes in more readable uable friendly on the user interface.

```
function bytesToSize(bytes, precision)
{  
   var kilobyte = 1024;
   var megabyte = kilobyte * 1024;
   var gigabyte = megabyte * 1024;
   var terabyte = gigabyte * 1024;
   if ((bytes >= 0) && (bytes < kilobyte)) {
       return bytes + ' B';
   } else if ((bytes >= kilobyte) && (bytes < megabyte)) {
       return (bytes / kilobyte).toFixed(precision) + ' KB';
   } else if ((bytes >= megabyte) && (bytes < gigabyte)) {
       return (bytes / megabyte).toFixed(precision) + ' MB';
   } else if ((bytes >= gigabyte) && (bytes < terabyte)) {
       return (bytes / gigabyte).toFixed(precision) + ' GB';
   } else if (bytes >= terabyte) {
       return (bytes / terabyte).toFixed(precision) + ' TB';
   } else {
       return bytes + ' B';
   }
}
```

However the problem is that it shows X KB, X MP ..etc (rounding the results to display on UI) and not able to show X.Y or say X,Y. After this thing thing came to my mind i was more confused and i started looking around the systems for how they show it on there UI. following are some of them,

1. FileZill : XXX,XXX,XXX bytes (while uploading)
2. Windows Explorer : XXX, XXX KB (in details view)

Now all these brought me to new level of confusion, as the size displayed on the UI using above function is not really precise imagine file size in GB's which is incorrectly displayed to user.

Please let know in which format this data should be displayed to the users to be more useful at the same time more accurate. Also real estate is expensive in today's complicated web pages which also needed to be considered.

Comment: in reality, how many users are going to have multi GB or even multi TB files?

Comment: And still, there are two types of size - the files size, and the actual size of the file on disk. The second one takes clusters size into account.

Comment: @Tom: very true, but its just another test case that we should test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick overview I like the file size format `xxx.x fooB` where `foo` the biggest applicable of `T, G, M, k` (or empty).

That is, divide `numBytes` by 1024 until it's `< 1000` using floating point arithmetic. Remember how often you divided, convert that to the according `foo`.

Of course you might want to consider other formats for detailed file size information.